# Is there any possibility that Amazon S3 will notify of a completed upload that actually failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Our application will depend upon uploads of fairly large files to an S3 Bucket via 3rd party apps like S3CMD (command line) and S3 Browser free version (GUI) for Windows from many locations around the world -- some with very shaky and slow internet connections.  It is highly likely that packets may get lost and internet may cut out unexpectedly.

The S3 Bucket will be configured to send notifications to an SNS Topic which will forward the message to our application rest endpoint, using an XML file inside the *notifications* subresource, following the instructions in the Documentation here:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

**1) Is there any remote chance that a failed or incomplete upload will be reported as complete?**

The notifications that can be sent to SNS seem to be fairly limited and there appears to be no method for conveying errors. The error notification documentation for S3 seems to be directed at someone implementing and handling their own upload mechanisms.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

**2) Am I correct that there is no way to setup forwarding such error messages to SNS?**

Answer (score 0):

The SDKs provide their own mechanisms for catching errors when an upload fails.

A failed upload (access denied, content-length mismatch, connection timeout, content-md5 mismatch, multipart never completed nor aborted, or any other reason) will not trigger a notification. There's not a way to generate events from failed uploads -- S3 wouldn't necessarily even be aware of the failure, depending on the cause of the failure.

Comment: "S3 wouldn't necessarily even be aware of the failure, depending on the cause of the failure."  What do you mean by "aware"? and what errors *might* s3 be aware of?

Comment: For example, if the initial connection failed due to network connectivity issues preventing the 3-way handshake or SSL negotiation, S3 would have no idea of who was trying what, so you'd have a failed upload and only the client end would be aware of it.  S3 might see the failed connection attempt, but not the actual request, and would thus be unaware of what action was being attempted (and failed).